# #selector function does not trigger for UIDatePicker

Tags: swift, swift5

I have a very simple `CustomIDatePicker` class written in **Swift 5**, which has a toolbar on top that contains a 'Done' button. The issue is, the function associated with this button never seem to get triggered.

```
class CustomDatePicker: UIDatePicker {

    var zTextField: UITextField!

    let toolbar = UIToolbar()

    // bar buttons
    let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed(sender:)))

    convenience init(textField: UITextField) {
        self.init()

        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        toolbar.setItems([doneBtn], animated: true)

        self.datePickerMode = .date

        // link up the Text Field
        zTextField = textField
        zTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        zTextField.inputView = self
    }

    @objc func donePressed (sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("done pressed") // this line fail to appear on the debugger
    }
}
```

A very simple ViewController to test this class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var theTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let datePicker = CustomDatePicker(textField: theTextField)
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should always tag your question with the basic language tag (swift) because that is what most people are monitoring and then if your question somehow relies to a specific version you can also use that specific version tag

Comment: So you think (correctly) that the line `let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed(sender:)))` is causing the issue.  Think about each parameter, what can you tell about why there are here, and what value you put? ie. why `nil`?

Comment: Thank you for the hint Larme. It was one of the mistakes in the original code. The answer below fixed the rest. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the target, in order to do that you need to move the bar button instantiation in the component init.

```swift
class CustomDatePicker: UIDatePicker {

    var zTextField: UITextField!

    let toolbar = UIToolbar()

    // bar buttons

    convenience init(textField: UITextField) {
        self.init()
        let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(donePressed(sender:)))
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        toolbar.setItems([doneBtn], animated: true)

        self.datePickerMode = .date

        // link up the Text Field
        zTextField = textField
        zTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        zTextField.inputView = self
    }

    @objc func donePressed (sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("done pressed") // this line fail to appear on the debugger
    }
}
```